# Can't access my RPI 3 using SSH

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+

I used to be able to SSH  my RPI without difficulty but on resurrecting my PI and reinstalling Raspbian SSH does not work.  I can ping the Pi OK.  I have tried switching off VPN and avast but still no luck. I have enabled SSH  Any suggestions would be appreciated as I have been trying to fix the problem for some time.

Comment: **Raspbian** is an old operating system. You should better use the up to date [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/). Please [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/127922/edit) your question and add the output of this command to it: `ssh -v pi@<ip-of-rpi>`.

Comment: This question is lacking any meaningful data. Did you enable ssh using raspi-config?

Answer (score 1):

If you are with Windows, plug SD card to Windows. Create aa empty file on boot directory, named "ssh". There should be no file extention, only "ssh". No "ssh.txt" etc. Be careful, Windows hides file extentions by default.
This process will enable ssh on your Raspbian

Comment: FYI: `ssh.txt` is perfectly acceptable. This was done because of the Windows feature you mention

Answer (score 0):

Enabling ssh at first boot requires an ssh file in the boot directory. If your sd card is mounted on another Linux system, you see a directory

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1     /run/media/username/boot
```

if you query all mounts. So do a

```
touch /run/media/username/boot/ssh
```

and ssh will start at boot-time.

Comment: Sorry, cut-and-pasted from my own website without the context of the first  boot (the OP wrote he re-installed). Added that context.